# Is it possible to stagger builds in Hudson/Jenkins?

Tags: build, hudson, jenkins, delay

I have Jenkins set up to build  XBMC images for different platforms.  My system takes around 6 hours to build each image, so I prefer to run them in parallel, usually 2 or 3 at a time.   The problem with this is, that if they have to download updates to modules (like linux kernel or sometihng), the 2 or 3 building in parallel will download at the same time, corrupting the download (they point to the same folder)

Is it possible in jenkins/hudson to specify an offset?  (I know you can schedule builds, as well as use a trigger that builds after completion of one project)  something like:

Build 1: immediately

Build 2: start 20 minutes after build 1

Build 3: start 20 minutes after build 2

I tried looking for a plugin as well as google but no luck.  I also know that I could schedule via the cron-like schedule capabilities in jenkins, but I have my build trigger set up to poll the GIT repo to look for changes for a build, I'm not just blind scheduling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it is to choose the "Quiet Period" option under "Advanced".
Set it to 1200 seconds for Job 2, and 2400 seconds for Job 3.

That means Job 1 will be queued immediately when a change is noticed in git, Job 2 will go into the queue with a 20 minute delay, and Job 3 with a 40 minute delay.

Comment: so even with setting it to poll for changes every 2 days, you're saying that by setting a quiet period to 1200/2400 seconds, it'll still pause the 2nd and 3rd jobs?  thats EXACTLY what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be to make the job some sort of a build flow (whether with the build flow plugin or by saying that the last task of job A is to run job B).  If you can turn the download into its own job, then you can define the "download" job as single-threaded, and the rest as multithreaded.

Doing this serializes only what needs to be serialized.  Doing an "every twenty minutes" thing will waste time when it takes fifteen minutes to download, and will fail (possibly in a hard-to-debug way) when there's a slowdown and it takes twenty-five minutes to download.